# mailbee send mail smtp error c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp

whats the reasons of this error

> n exception of type 'MailBee.MailBeeSocketTimeoutException' occurred in MailBee.NET.4.dll but was not handled in user cod
>   Additional information: Socket connection has timed out. InnerException message follows: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

edited

```
string str ="";
MailBee.Global.LicenseKey = "";
Smtp mailer = new Smtp(); 
SmtpServer server = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com", "", "");
server.SslMode = SslStartupMode.UseStartTls;
mailer.SmtpServers.Add(server);
mailer.BodyHtmlText = str;
mailer.From.Email = "info.likeland@gmail.com";
mailer.To.Add(email);             
mailer.Subject = "";
if (mailer.Send())
{
   return Json(new JsonData()
   {
      DntSuccess = true,
      DntHtml = ""
   });
}
```

it. happen for no reason.
what should I do

Comment: You should share the corresponding code.

Comment: you can see now

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable logging into a file using mailer.Log property, then retry and see what's in the log now. This will show you to which port the component is trying to connect to, etc. From that, you'll be able to understand what to do next (e.g. open a port in your firewall or try another port if the current one is blocked on your ISP level).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but finally have figured it out.
The problem is MailBee uses port 465 instead of 587.

```
Private Sub Send_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Send.Click
    Try
        Dim mailer As New Smtp
        Dim server As SmtpServer = New SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com", "email", "password")

        server.Port = 587

        mailer.SmtpServers.Add(server)
        mailer.From.Email = txtFrom.Text
        mailer.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
        mailer.Subject = txtSubject.Text
        mailer.BodyPlainText = txtMessage.Text
        mailer.Send()

        MsgBox("Mail Sent!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```